# wget is unable to resolve host address 80% of the time

Tags: networking, dns, wget

I have a `wget 'http://xxxx.net/somepage.asp?params@abc'` in a bash file.

When I run it, four out of five times it says:

```
Resolving xxxx.net (xxxx.net)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'xxxx.net'
```

Thinking that there was a problem with my DNS server, I added a `ping -c 2 xxxx.net` before wget.  Ping is 100% positively resolved all the time.

What could be the cause?  Does `wget` have its own method of resolving names?  This is on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically they should both use the same way of resolving addresses, however `ping` is likely not going to try resolving IPv6 addresses at all (AAAA records) and query directly A records as it's an IPv4-only tool (`ping6` does IPv6 ICMP requests).

A configuration issue I've seen in some load-balancing DNS servers backed by *named* (the same should apply no mater what backs the dymamic DNS resolver) is that when there is an A record in the load-balancing configuration and nothing for the same name in *named*, a request for the AAAA record falls back to *named* which respond with an *NXDomain* error (no such domain), preventing the resolver from attempting any other requests. One fix is adding an A, TXT or other compatible record for that name so when *named* catches an AAAA request it will not return an address nor return *NXDomain*, so the the client will go on and look for an A record.

If you have no control over the DNS server, using `wget --inet4-only` option may help. If that solves your issue you should also tell the domain owner about the DNS issue.

Comment: Thanks. `wget -4 ...` works, for all the times I tested. Are you saying that `wget` by default uses IPv6 first?  BTW: the domain is on 1and1.

Comment: I meet the same problem with 1and1's smtp server. In Python, `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.1and1.com')`, which instantiates the Smtp server, can't find the host three quarters of the time.

Comment: @OldGeezer if -4 works, then likely there is a problem with the DNS server when resolving IPv6 addresses. You can check with `dig AAAA <name>` vs `dig A <name>`.

On a good server you will see no answer to AAAA but you will see somewhere `status: NOERROR`. On a broken server you will see `status: NXDOMAIN` instead. The A lookup should return an `ANSWER SECTION:`. NXDomain must not be returned when there is a valid record of a different type for the name.

Comment: Are you referring to the DNS server of my running client (which is the router firmware on the home network I am connected to) or the authoritative name server for that domain name?

Comment: @OldGeezer I'm talking about the authoritative dns, but you may be able to get the answer from your local dns server too. It's true that if your local server cached an address already it may not show the behavior, but if you do an AAAA lookup on a clean cache you should see the NXDomain error there too. You can get the DNS servers from the parent domain with `dig NS <domain>`, and you can direct dns queries at those servers with: `dig AAAA <name> @<nameserver>` (no space between `@` and the nameserver).